# How to open link in new Tab by pressing Button? in jade

Tags: javascript, html, pug

The following

```
button(type="button", target="_blank", onclick="location.href='auth/google';")
```

does not work. It opens link in the same window. Just for reference, its part of node.js program, in which i'm using passportjs for google authentication.

Comment: Why don't you make an anchor tag?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The button isn't actually opening a link - it's just running some javascript code that happens to, in this instance, be navigating to a new URL. So the `target="_blank"` attribute on the button won't help.

Instead, you need to use javascript commands to open a new tab/window, rather than using javascript to change the URL of the current window. Assigning to `location.href` will only change the URL of the current window.

Use the `window.open(url, target)` function instead - it takes a URL, and a target window name, which behaves the same as the `target="whatever"` attribute on a link.

```
window.open('auth/google', '_blank');
```

Your complete code would look like this:

```
button(type="button", onclick="window.open('auth/google', '_blank');")
```

Comment: You saved me friend :) (y)